# Custom field value appearing in Sandbox but not appearing in Production vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a "birthdate__c" custom field in a custom object named "Client__c"
I have a lookup relationship on my custom object "Client__c" to another custom object named "InvestmentSchedule__c".
I'm calling the field "birthdate__c" of "Client__c" object using the lookup relationship from "Investmentschedule__c" object on a visualforce page.

Now the issue is
In Sandbox the field value is appearing ok on the visualforce page but in the production I'm not getting the field value.
I've check the site settings, field level security, field accessibility, the permissions are ok.
Please help. 
[image]
[image]

---

The vf page is too big to enter here, but this is the code that i've used to populate the field values

```
<table style="margin-right:px;margin-left:2px;  border-bottom: 1px solid #0168B3; "  border="" width="99.5%" cellspacing="5px" bgcolor="#E3F3FB">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="10" id="heading" style="background-color: #E3F3FB;"> <b>3.</b> SCHEME MEMBER DETAILS</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table  style=" padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="5px">    
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"> <b>First Scheme Member</b></td>
                        <td colspan="3"> <b>Second Scheme Member</b> </td>
                    </tr>        
                   <tr>
                        <td width="25%"> Title  <i>(Mr, Mrs, Miss)</i> </td>
                        <td width="15%" class="TitleClass">{!objIS.Application__r.Title__c}</td>
                        <td width="10%" class="">  </td>
                        <td width="25%"> Title  <i>(Mr, Mrs, Miss)</i> </td>
                        <td width="15%" class="TitleClass">  </td>
                        <td width="10%" class="">  </td>
                    </tr> 

                     </table>
                <table  style=" padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="5px">            
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">   Surname  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass" width="25%">{!objIS.Client__r.Last_name__c}</td>
                        <td width="25%">   Surname  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass" width="25%"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   First Name </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Client__r.First_Name__c}</td>
                        <td>   First Name  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Middle Name(s)  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Client__r.Middle_Name__c}</td>
                        <td>   Middle Name(s) </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Nationality  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Application__r.App_Citizenship__c}</td>
                        <td>   Nationality  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                <!--</table>
                <br/><br/>
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="5px"> --> 
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">   Gender </td>
                        <td width="25%" class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Client__r.Gender__c}</td>
                        <td width="25%">   Gender </td>
                        <td width="25%" class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Date of Birth </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!CDOB_Day}/{!CDOB_Month}/{!CDOB_Year}</td>
                        <td>   Date of Birth </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Home Telephone Number </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Application__r.Client_Phone_Landline__c}</td>
                        <td>   Home Telephone Number </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Work Telephone Number  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                        <td>   Work Telephone Number </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Mobile Number </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Application__r.Client_Phone_Mobile__c}</td>
                        <td>   Mobile Number  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>        
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Email Address </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Application__r.Client_email_address__c}</td>
                        <td>   Email Address  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Address </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass" style="height:60px;">{!objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_1__c}<br/>  
                                                                      {!objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_2__c}<br/>
                                                                      {!objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_3__c}<br/>
                                                                      {!objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_Town__c} {!objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_Country__c}
                        </td>
                        <td >   Address  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass" style="height:60px;"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   Postcode  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass">{!objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_Postcode__c}</td>
                        <td>   Postcode  </td>
                        <td class="TextBoxClass"> </td>
                    </tr>        
                </table>
                </td></tr></table>
                <br/><br/><br/>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class Banks_Controller
{
    public Investment_Schedule__c objInvestmentSchedule { get; set; }
    public Investment_Schedule__c objIS{get;set;}

    public String startdateOutput{get;set;}
    public String birthdateOutput{get;set;}
    public String titleStr { get;set;}
    public String FullName {get;set;}
    public String MobileStr{get;set;}
    public string alocationamount {get; set;}
    public List<String> amountbreak {get; set;}
    public string drate{get; set;}
    public string term{get; set;}
    public string bobterm{get; set;}

    public String FD_Year{get;set;}
    public String FD_Year1{get;set;}
    public String FD_Year2{get;set;}
    public String FD_Year3{get;set;}
    public String FD_Year4{get;set;}

    public string RS_Year{get;set;}
    public string RS_Year1{get;set;}
    public string RS_Year2{get;set;}
    public string RS_Year3{get;set;}
    public string RS_Year4{get;set;}

    public string PRS_Year{get;set;}
    public string PRS_Year1{get;set;}
    public string PRS_Year2{get;set;}
    public string PRS_Year3{get;set;}
    public string PRS_Year4{get;set;}

    public String PDS1_OtherTitle{get;set;}
    public String strAddressLine3{get;set;}
    public String strClientAddress2{get;set;}
    public String strClientAddress1{get;set;}
    public String isInstantAccess{get;set;}

    public String CDOB_Year{get;set;}
    public String CDOB_Year1{get;set;}
    public String CDOB_Year2{get;set;}
    public String CDOB_Year3{get;set;}
    public String CDOB_Year4{get;set;}
    public String Term_Deposit_In_Months{get;set;}
    public string[] myList{get;set;}

    public Boolean MrTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean MrsTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean MissTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean DrTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean MSTitle{get;set;}

    public Integer FD_Day{get;set;}
    public Integer FD_Day1{get;set;}
    public Integer FD_Day2{get;set;}
    public Integer FD_Month{get;set;}
    public Integer FD_Month1{get;set;}
    public Integer FD_Month2{get;set;}

    public Integer RS_Month{get;set;}
    public Integer RS_Month1{get;set;}
    public Integer RS_Month2{get;set;}

    public Integer PRS_Month{get;set;}
    public Integer PRS_Month1{get;set;}
    public Integer PRS_Month2{get;set;}

    //public String clientBirthdate{get;set;}
    public Integer CDOB_Day{get;set;}
    public Integer CDOB_Day1{get;set;}
    public Integer CDOB_Day2{get;set;}
    public Integer CDOB_Month{get;set;}
    public Integer CDOB_Month1{get;set;}
    public Integer CDOB_Month2{get;set;}

    //Personal Details (Signature 1)
    public Boolean PDS1_MrTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean PDS1_MrsTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean PDS1_MissTitle{get;set;}
    public Boolean PDS1_DrTitle{get;set;}

    public String AmtInWords{get;set;}
    public String AmtInWordsInPenny{get;set;}

    public Integer termInYears{get;set;}
    public Integer termInMonths{get;set;}
    public Integer termInYearsbob{get;set;}
    public Integer termInMonthsbob{get;set;}


    public Banks_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        try{
            isInstantAccess = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('type')=='Instant Access'?'yes':'no';
            alocationamount = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('alcamt');
            amountbreak = alocationamount.split('\\.');
            drate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('drate');

            term = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('term');
            Integer temp = Integer.valueOf(term)-1;
            bobterm = string.valueOf(temp);

            termInYearsbob = Integer.valueOf(bobterm)/12;
            termInMonthsbob = Math.MOD(Integer.valueOf(bobterm),12);

            termInYears = Integer.valueOf(term)/12;
            termInMonths = Math.MOD(Integer.valueOf(term),12);

            System.debug('****Term****'+term);
            System.debug('****Term in Years****'+termInYears);
            System.debug('****Term in Months****'+termInMonths);

            AmtInWords=NumberToWord.english_number(Long.valueOf(string.valueOf(Decimal.valueOf(amountbreak[0]).setScale(0))));
            AmtInWordsInPenny=NumberToWord.english_number(Long.valueOf(string.valueOf(Decimal.valueOf(amountbreak[1]).setScale(0))));

            titleStr='';
            objIS = new Investment_Schedule__c();
            Id recordid = controller.getRecord().id;
            objIS = [select id, quote__r.name, quote__r.Whole_Years_In_Term__c,quote__r.Additional_Months_In_Term__c,Client__r.name,adviser__r.name,
            contact__r.name,Application__r.Investment_Date__c,Client__r.Postcode__c, Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c, Client__r.Gender__c,Application__r.Title_Other__c,
            Client__r.Telephone_landline__c,Client__r.Email__c, Client__r.Salutation__c,Client__r.First_Name__c, Client__r.Last_name__c,Application__r.App_previous_address__c,
            Client__r.Middle_Name__c,Application__r.Title__c,Application__r.App_Client_Address_1__c,Application__r.App_Client_Address_2__c, Application__r.Resident_at_address_since__c,
            Application__r.App_Client_Address_3__c, Application__r.App_Client_Address_Town__c,Application__r.App_Client_Address_Country__c,Application__r.App_Passport_or_DVLA_number__c,
            Application__r.App_Client_Address_Postcode__c,Application__r.Client_Marital_Status__c, Application__r.Client_Date_of_Birth__c, Application__r.App_Citizenship__c,
            Application__r.Client_Phone_Landline__c, Application__r.Client_Phone_Mobile__c, Application__r.Client_email_address__c, Application__r.App_Country_of_residence__c,
            Application__r.App_previous_address_resident_since__c, Application__r.App_previous_address_postcode__c, Application__r.App_previous_address_Country_of_residenc__c,
            application__r.App_Account_Term_Months__c,application__r.App_Account_Term_Years__c,Application__r.Client_first_name__c,Application__r.Client_Surname__c,
            Application__r.Client_middle_name_s__c
            FROM investment_schedule__c where id =: recordid];
            System.debug('Investment Schedule Object '+objIS);

            if(objIS!=null){
                Datetime startDate = objIS.Application__r.Investment_Date__c;
                startdateOutput = startDate.format('MMMM d,  yyyy'); 
                if(objIS.Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c!=null) { 
                    startDate = objIS.Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c;
                    birthdateOutput= startDate.format('MMMM d,  yyyy');
                }

                //Title Checkbox
                if(objIS.Client__r.Salutation__c == 'Mr.'){ MrTitle=True; }
                else if(objIS.Client__r.Salutation__c == 'Mrs'){ MrsTitle=True; }
                else if(objIS.Client__r.Salutation__c == 'Miss'){ MissTitle=True; }
                else if(objIS.Client__r.Salutation__c == 'Dr'){ DrTitle=True; }
                else if(objIS.Client__r.Salutation__c == 'M/S'){ MSTitle=True;}

                FullName= ((objIS.Client__r.First_Name__c !=null)?objIS.Client__r.First_Name__c :'') +' ' +
                          ((objIS.Client__r.Middle_Name__c!=null)?objIS.Client__r.Middle_Name__c:'')+' ' +
                          ((objIS.Client__r.Last_name__c !=null)?objIS.Client__r.Last_name__c:'');

                FD_Day=objIS.Application__r.Investment_Date__c.Day();
                FD_Month=objIS.Application__r.Investment_Date__c.Month();
                FD_Year=String.valueOf(objIS.Application__r.Investment_Date__c.Year());
                //Get Day seperated 
                if(FD_Day<10){ 
                    FD_Day1=0; 
                    FD_Day2=FD_Day;
                }
                else{ 
                    FD_Day1=FD_Day/10; 
                    FD_Day2=Math.MOD(FD_Day,10); 
                }

                //Get month seperated 
                if(FD_Month<10){
                    FD_Month1=0;
                    FD_Month2=FD_Month;
                }
                else{
                    FD_Month1=1;
                    FD_Month2=Math.MOD(FD_Month,10);
                }
                //Get Year Seperated
                FD_Year1=FD_Year.subString(0,1);
                FD_Year2=FD_Year.subString(1,2);
                FD_Year3=FD_Year.subString(2,3);
                FD_Year4=FD_Year.subString(3,4);

                // Residing Since            
                if(objIS.Application__r.Resident_at_address_since__c!=null){
                    RS_Month=objIS.Application__r.Resident_at_address_since__c.Month();
                    RS_Year=String.valueOf(objIS.Application__r.Resident_at_address_since__c.Year());

                    if(RS_Month<10){
                        RS_Month1=0;
                        RS_Month2=RS_Month;
                    }
                    else{
                        RS_Month1=1;
                        RS_Month2=Math.MOD(RS_Month,10);
                    }
                    RS_Year1=RS_Year.subString(0,1);
                    RS_Year2=RS_Year.subString(1,2);
                    RS_Year3=RS_Year.subString(2,3);
                    RS_Year4=RS_Year.subString(3,4);

                    // Previous residing since
                    PRS_Month=objIS.Application__r.App_previous_address_resident_since__c.Month();
                    PRS_Year=String.valueOf(objIS.Application__r.App_previous_address_resident_since__c.Year());

                    if(PRS_Month<10){
                        PRS_Month1=0;
                        PRS_Month2=PRS_Month;
                    }
                    else{
                        PRS_Month1=1;
                        PRS_Month2=Math.MOD(PRS_Month,10);
                    }
                    PRS_Year1=PRS_Year.subString(0,1);
                    PRS_Year2=PRS_Year.subString(1,2);
                    PRS_Year3=PRS_Year.subString(2,3);
                    PRS_Year4=PRS_Year.subString(3,4);
                }

                 //Title Checkbox - Personal Details (Signature 1)

                 if(objIS.Application__r.Title__c == 'Mr.'){ PDS1_MrTitle=True;}
                else if(objIS.Application__r.Title__c == 'Mrs'){ PDS1_MrsTitle=True; }
                else if(objIS.Application__r.Title__c == 'Miss'){PDS1_MissTitle=True; }
                else if(objIS.Application__r.Title__c == 'Dr'){ PDS1_DrTitle=True; }
                else { PDS1_OtherTitle=objIS.Application__r.Title__c;}

                //Client Address
                strAddressLine3= ((objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_3__c==null)?'':objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_3__c)+ 
                                ' ' +(objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_Town__c==null?'':objIS.Application__r.App_Client_Address_Town__c);

                //Client Birthdate
                if(objIS.Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c!=null){
                    CDOB_Day=objIS.Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c.Day();
                    CDOB_Month=objIS.Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c.Month();
                    CDOB_Year=String.valueOf(objIS.Client__r.PersonBirthdate__c.Year());            
                    //Get Day seperated 
                    if(CDOB_Day<10){ 
                        CDOB_Day1=0; 
                        CDOB_Day2=CDOB_Day;
                    }
                    else{ 
                        CDOB_Day1=CDOB_Day/10; 
                        CDOB_Day2=Math.MOD(CDOB_Day,10); 
                    }            
                    //Get month seperated 
                    if(CDOB_Month<10){
                        CDOB_Month1=0;
                        CDOB_Month2=CDOB_Month;
                    }
                    else{
                        CDOB_Month1=1;
                        CDOB_Month2=Math.MOD(CDOB_Month,10);
                    }
                    //Get Year Seperated
                    CDOB_Year1=CDOB_Year.subString(0,1);
                    CDOB_Year2=CDOB_Year.subString(1,2);
                    CDOB_Year3=CDOB_Year.subString(2,3);
                    CDOB_Year4=CDOB_Year.subString(3,4);
                }

                Term_Deposit_In_Months = string.valueOf(objIS.quote__r.Whole_Years_In_Term__c * 12 + objIS.quote__r.Additional_Months_In_Term__c);
                //objIS.Application__r.Client_Phone_Mobile__c = '123456';
                if(objIS.Application__r.Client_Phone_Mobile__c!=null){
                    MobileStr = string.valueOf(objIS.Application__r.Client_Phone_Mobile__c);
                    List<string> strList = MobileStr.split('');
                    myList = new List<string>();
                    Integer lstSize = strList.size()+(12-strList.size());
                    for(Integer i=1;i<lstSize; i++){
                        if(i>=strList.size())
                            myList.add(' ');
                        else
                            myList.add(strList[i]);
                    }
                    //myList = MobileStr.split('');
                }
            }}
            catch(Exception ex){
                //Integer.valueOf( ex.getMessage()+ex.getStackTraceString());
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.error, ex.getMessage()+ex.getStackTraceString());
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your Apex & Visualforce code for the page.

Comment: Are you sure the data is populated correctly in Production? You say you have a custom field called `Birthdate__c`, but in your Apex you are referencing a field called `PersonBirthdate__c`

Comment: Sorry my mistake in typing, its PersonBirthdate__c. the code that i've pasted above is the production code.
I've break the PersonBirthdate__c & then i've used it in the VF pages.
I'm getting the date in the query, I've printed it in Debug Logs

Answer (score 1):

It was throwing a null pointer exception. the field value was empty & i didn't gave an if condition to its its null & because of that it was taking null & was giving exception but as i wrote the code in try catch it was not giving a error.
so applied a if condition to check if the field value is null or not & my issue is resolved.
Thanks everyone for you idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest solution would be if the field "birthdate__c" of "Client__c" object is named somewhat differently in Production than in Sandbox. If only all problems were this easy, right?

Comment: I've crossed checked it. Its same as Sandbox

Comment: Maybe the date format/locale is different in production so the date fields are not in DD/MM/YYYY format? In that cae it might try to push 18 as a month and fail miserably. But you can guess I'm trying my best before embracing the fact that we will have to go through the code =)

Comment: I have break the field value & typecasted its data type to string & then displaying it on the vf page

Comment: Yeah I see now. Time to indulge in the sinnery of looking into other peroson's code

Comment: Please since morning i'm looking into that issue, not able to fix it, I have 8 vf & all of them having the same issue with the date of birth

Comment: Have you checked the field security permissions for Client__c and PersonBirthdate__c? If you deployed the fields from sandbox and did not also deploy their profile settings, no-one will be able to view them. That would cause the result you're seeing

Comment: there is no specific profile is created for any user, its only onc user that is admin who will be doing all the operations.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for that I see is PersonBirthdate__c field not having correct Field level security set on Production.

Can you check once if that is set correctly?

Comment: Its Working now i've not checked the null value for another field value & because of that i was getting null pointer exception & the date value was not getting evaluated. I wrote the code in try catch so was not getting error.
I've put a if condition for the another field value & now i'm able to get the birthdate on the vf page.